# Is it OK to nail 1/2" plywood straight to the pocket-door box?

Tags: framing, plywood, pocket-door

The guy I hired to frame for a new pocket-door, mounted the pocket-door box on the top (to a second-story joist) and on the bottom (toe-nailed to the floor). When I asked him to install some studs on both sides of the door, he said I don't need them because I can nail my wall material (1/2" plywood) right into the horizontal planks of the pocket-door box. I have a feeling that would be wrong, or at least not up to Code. What do you think? Any advice is very much appreciated. I am new to this, just learning the terms. But it really didn't seem safe..

Answer (score 2):

The 'boxes' made for pocket doors are designed to act as the framing for your wall material (typically sheetrock). You topically can't frame out the pocket door pocket with full studs as that'd make the wall too thick.